# Normal Distribution pattern in Java Array of doubles

Tags: pattern-recognition, java

Given ordered array of float numbers, Check if array represents Normal Distribution.

I wrote algo to find triangular distribution as follows:

```
1. Find index "i" in array such that sum {A[0] + ...A[i-1]} almost equal to sum {A[i] + ... + A[n-1]}
2. Check if A[i....i-1] is almost increasing sequence
3. Check if A[i ... n -1] is almost decreasing sequence
```

I need to upgrade this to normal distribution ? Is there good Java lib that identifies Normal Distribution pattern Or is there well known algorithm to solve this problem

Comment: Implementation specific questions are off-topic here. Have you seen [normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test) at Wikipedia? There are a lots if tests of this kind.

Comment: Hasn't this been posted before? It looks very familiar.

Comment: [Also posted on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/327754/34181).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.